# I need an alternative for Tubedigger

Tags: windows, gratis, screen-recording, download-manager, video-recording

I need an alternative to Tubedigger software, it is paid. I want to use its record mode functionality so anything with that would do. I used its latest version 7.3.1 and it works but its older versions don't work.

Tubedigger is a software for Windows used to download videos from sites. It has built-in Chromium browser interface. So we can just navigate to a site we please and it will grab the video files from there and download it. If it can't download the video, it has a record mode that will internally record the playing video and give it as a whole mp4 file.

More importantly, I need to use its record its record functionality, so any alternative with that will do.

Tubedigger's trial has a limit for record functionality and costs $25. Unfortunately, I cannot afford it at all.